# Excel. Greater than or equal in consecutive number

Tags: excel

I have a list of 2 columns:
A - dates & times (MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS), called DATETIME
B - Temperatures F°, called TEMP

I need to extract numbers for the following (all in sequential order) [sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CooaM.png) (red font are the values I'm supposed to get with the formulas):

1st => 100

2nd <= 210

3rd => 235

4th <= 260

5th => 265

6th <= 160

I've tried different formulas for each, because apparently not all work:

1st - INDEX(TEMP,MATCH(TRUE,TEMP>=100,0))

2nd - VLOOKUP(210,TEMP,1,TRUE)

3rd - INDEX(TEMP,MATCH(TRUE,TEMP>=235,0))

4th - VLOOKUP(260,TEMP,1,TRUE)

5th - SMALL(TEMP,COUNTIF(TEMP,"<="&265)) ***THIS IS THE COOL DOWN, SO NEEDS TO BE THE LAST VALUE

6th - SMALL(TEMP,COUNTIF(TEMP,"<="&160))

For some reason, the formulas worked 80% of the time, but there are files with larger number of rows (same format) and the program grabs different values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the addresses into you sheet.

Try this:

```
1st =SMALL(IF($B$2:$B$28>F3,ABS($B$2:$B$28-F3),1048576),1)+F3
2nd =-SMALL(IF($B$2:$B$28>F4,ABS($B$2:$B$28-G3),1048576),1)+G3
3rd =SMALL(IF($B$2:$B$28>H3,ABS($B$2:$B$28-H3),1048576),1)+H3
4th =-SMALL(IF($B$2:$B$28>H4,ABS($B$2:$B$28-I3),1048576),1)+I3
5th =SMALL(IF($B$2:$B$28>J3,ABS($B$2:$B$28-J3),1048576),1)+J3
6th =-SMALL(IF($B$2:$B$28<J4,ABS($B$2:$B$28-K3),1048576),1)+K3
```

[image]

Comment: First of all, thank you, I tried your formulas and work pretty good, however the intent is use the native csv file and import it, without doing anything else. The problem I'm having is that some formulas, like vlookup the values have to be in ascending order, however there are days that it extends and instead of dropping to 150 and the stoppping, its running until it stops at 90 and the the spreadsheet gets confused as to which value is the right one. 
All above is being programmed in vba, & like I said is working 80% of the time when the cool down stops at 150.

Comment: Well I think the solution to this is to calculate diferent parameters for each csv, like the 5th value could the maximum, the first could be 10% over the minimum, and so on